# How to retrieve all project areas from a Java Team Server?

Tags: java, authentication, rest, jazz

I installed a local Java Team Server, version 3.0.1. I'm trying to use the REST web services to retrieve all the project areas. For that I first authenticated myself:

```
public HttpContext login() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpGet httpGetID = new HttpGet("https://localhost:9443/ccm/authenticated/identity");
        client.execute(httpGetID, localContext);
        httpGetID.abort();

        List<Cookie> cookies1 = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies1) {
            System.out.println("\t"+cookie.getName()+" : "+cookie.getValue());
        }

        List<NameValuePair> authFormParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        authFormParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "ADMIN"));
        authFormParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "ADMIN"));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(authFormParams, "UTF-8");
        HttpPost httpPostAuth = new HttpPost("https://localhost:9443/ccm/authenticated/j_security_check");
        httpPostAuth.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        httpPostAuth.setEntity(entity);
        client.execute(httpPostAuth, localContext);
        //httpPostAuth.abort();

        List<Cookie> cookies2 = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies2) {
            System.out.println("\t"+cookie.getName()+" : "+cookie.getValue());
        }

        return localContext;
    }
```

Then I try to get the project areas with the following code:

```
HttpGet getProjectsRequest = new HttpGet("https://localhost:9443/ccm/oslc-scm/catalog");
        getProjectsRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        getProjectsRequest.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        getProjectsRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/x-oslc-cm-change-request+xml");

        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String projectResponse = client.execute(getProjectsRequest, handler, localContext);
        System.out.println(projectResponse);
```

Unfortunately, the answer is always the same:

```
{
    "userId": "ADMIN",
    "roles": [
        "JazzUsers",
        "JazzProjectAdmins",
        "JazzAdmins"]
}
```

This looks for me like a JSON object. Instead I should get a XML document, that lists all projects. I already tried the same REST service with a REST plugin for Firefox. There I get the XML document as expected. However, I can't see any differences between my code and the things I do in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer [here](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=52062).

Here is what I understood: basically, you need to visit another page to receive a cookie and then run your query. Just run the same execute twice and you see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can get All Project Areas of a particular user using [DraftTeamProcessRestAPIs](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/DraftTeamProcessRestApi)

and in particular see this [section](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/DraftTeamProcessRestApi#GET_project_areas_collection)

This API responses in XML

and also there are [ReportableRestAPIs](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ReportsRESTAPI#Getting_a_schema_for_a_resource) which can fulfill what you want using this URL in the code:

```
 https://<server>:<port>/ccm/rpt/repository/foundation?fields=foundation/projectArea/(name|teamMembers/userId)
```